# How to create Notification which avoid TaskManager's killing?

Tags: java, android

I want to create Notification in Android.
But, If I kill the application via TaskManager, it terminate the Notification too..
It is the code-snipet.

it is the caller.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity, NotificationReciever.class);
String appName = myActivity.getTitle().toString();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, time);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
myActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

it is the Reciever.

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

I added the code, but it can't

```
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
```

I' like to make alive the Notification.
Would you tell me how to avoid the TaskManager's killing?

Answer (score 0):

> Would you tell me how to avoid the TaskManager's killing?

That is not possible, except perhaps via a custom build of the Android OS, put into your own ROM mod to deploy on your own devices.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can't modify rom, because I must modify everyone's device which downloaded my Game...

Comment: If I use C language and JNI, is it possible?